# How to use filter function within another function

Tags: google-apps-script, filter, google-sheets

I am new to programming in google sheets. I have found code to create a custom menu and used it to hide specific columns in a sheet (The menu selection allows users to select a particular view of the data in a google sheet without being able to edit the raw data). Once the columns are hidden, I then want to use a filter for the data based on values in a particular column (Ticket Type). I can't figure out how to get the code for the filter to run after the columns are hidden. I've tried many variations (including reference to a second function) and looked up functions within a function, but haven't had success in finding a solution. I am thinking I can filter similar to hiding columns, but it isn't working. Suggestions on how to make it work?

```
function showReservationView() {
    {
        var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
        showAll();
        sheet.hideColumn(sheet.getRange("B1:F1"));
        sheet.hideColumn(sheet.getRange("H1"));
        sheet.hideColumn(sheet.getRange("K1:U1"));
        sheet.hideColumn(sheet.getRange("W1:Z1"));
        sheet.hideColumn(sheet.getRange("AB1:AK1"));
        sheet.hideColumn(sheet.getRange("AM1"));
        sheet.hideColumn(sheet.getRange("AO1:AP1"));
        sheet.hideColumn(sheet.getRange("AR1:BC1"));
        sheet.hideColumn(sheet.getRange("BE1:BR1"));
    }
    function setFilter() {
        var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        var filterSettings = {};

        filterSettings.range = {
            sheetId: ss.getActiveSheet().getSheetId()
        };

        // Criteria for showing/hiding rows in a filter
        // https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/FilterCriteria
        filterSettings.criteria = {};
        var columnIndex = 7;
        filterSettings['criteria'][columnIndex] = {
            'hiddenValues': [
                "EARLY BIRD - Top Tier Full Week Residential Pass",
                "Top Tier Full Week Residential Pass",
                "GROUP DISCOUNT - Top Tier Full Week Residential Pass",
                "EARLY BIRD - Middle Tier Residential Pass",
                "Middle Tier Residential Pass",
                "GROUP DISCOUNT - Middle Tier Residential Pass",
                "EARLY BIRD - Courtyard Room Pass",
                "Courtyard Room Pass",
                "GROUP DISCOUNT - Courtyard Room Pass",
                "Non-Residential Week Pass",
                "GROUP DISCOUNT - Non-Residential Week Pass",
                "Indian Citizen Week Pass",
                "Day Pass",
                "Donation to the Swami Shukdevanand Trust",
                "Teacher/Presenter Ticket",
                "Sevak Ticket",
                "Infant Ticket",
                "Media Day Pass",
                "Media Non-Residential Week Pass",
                "Media Residential Week Pass",
                "Special Guest Residential Pass"
            ]
        };

        var request = {
            "setBasicFilter": {
                "filter": filterSettings
            }
        };
        Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({'requests': [request]}, ss.getId());
    }
}
```

Comment: What isn't working? Exactly *how* is it "not working"? Just saying "it doesn't work" is not a valid problem description. Provide error messages and detailed description of what differed from your expected behavior, for each attempt you made. This shows your effort in attempting to find the solution. You should also provide evidence of the research you did into solving your issue. You say you found code to do this - why wouldn't you cite the actual author?

Comment: Note that you define the filter function inside the definition of the other function. While valid, this means you cannot use your `setFilter` function from any other code except `showReservationView` as it is not in the global namespace of your Script Project

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your feedback and questions. For the custom menu, I used this link: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/82666/google-sheets-customize-view-using-create-custom-menu-and-hiding-showing-specifc. I modified the menu names and the columns to be hidden according to what I needed. The function works fine. I am able to hide different sets of columns based on the menu chosen from the custom menu. The next step is I would like to apply a filter based on the ticket type: https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/learn-by-example/google-sheets-api/filters.

Comment: I used the code from this google link: https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/learn-by-example/google-sheets-api/filters. I realize it is a second filter. So, these are my citations.

Comment: The SetFilter function is set within another function - and isn't running. The columns hide fine, but the filter doesn't apply. I am okay for now with the filter function running for only 1 view. I have not been able to find any references to running a function inside another function.

Answer (score 0):

Your code just declares that the variable `setFilter` is a reference to a [function object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions) - it never [calls / invokes the function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Calling_functions). Until you attempt to call a function object, that's all it is - an object reference. Even if it is a reference to a function object.

Nesting the declaration of `setFilter` as a function object within a function (e.g. `function foo()`) means that no other functions outside of function `foo` can access that particular function object. Some other function (or global) could say that `setFilter` is a variable with value 1:

```
var setFilter = 1; // globally scope `setFilter` to be value 1.
function foo() {
  Logger.log(typeof setFilter); // number
  try { setFilter() }
  catch (err) { Logger.log(err) } // TypeError: setFilter is not a function, it is number.
}
function foo2() {
  // Define what `setFilter` means within the context (namespace scope) of `foo2`
  // This declaration will shadow the global declaration within this function context.
  function setFilter() { /** code */ };
  Logger.log(typeof setFilter); // function
  setFilter(); // no TypeError from calling a non-function
}
```

To summarize the linked function guide, you need to do something like this:

```
function showReservationView() {
  function setFilter(/** add parameters for the function here */) {
    // code here
  }

  // Treat the nearest namespace scope declaration of `showAll` as 
  // a function object by calling it.
  showAll();

  // Hide all the column ranges we want to hide.
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet(),
        rangesToHide = [
          "B1:F1", "H1", "K1:U1", "W1:Z1", "AB1:AK1",
          "AM1", "AO1:AP1", "AR1:BC1", "BE1:BR1"
        ];
  sheet.getRangeList(rangesToHide).getRanges().forEach(function (rg) {
    sheet.hideColumn(rg);
  });

  // Treat the nearest namespace scope declaration of `setFilter` as 
  // a function object by calling it.
  setFilter();
}
```

References:

- [MDN Function Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions)
- [Array#forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [`RangeList`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list)